# Making the VBA code affect a specific range of pages

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sorting, tabs

I have this very simple code

```
    Sub SortByTime()
'
' SortByTime Macro
' Sort by Time
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M
'
    Range("C4:J43").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-36
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("G4:G43") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("C3:J43")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

what I'm trying to do is make this code affect on 365 sheets, (not all of the workbook sheets) I have 30 sheets for each month,
I did not know how to edit this code,
I tried to add the sheets like this,
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Jan_1"+"Jan_2"+"Jan_3"+"Jan_4"+"Jan_5"+.... etc ).Sort

but it did not work

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand this line .Worksheets("Jan_1" + "Jan_2") and even more so the line .Worksheets("Jan_1"+"Jan_2"+"Jan_3"+"Jan_4"+"Jan_5"+.... etc ). The documentation for the [**Worksheet object (Excel)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) states that you will only get one sheet at a time: *Use Worksheets (index), where index is the worksheet index number or name, to return a **single** Worksheet object*. Is there a sheet in your workbook called **"Jan_1Jan_2"**? Otherwise, the code you provided will not work.

Comment: @JohnSUN, thanks for your reply, I edited the code above, maybe now it's more clear, and actually this is what I used, and it's working very well, for one sheet, as for the other sheets, I have to create a new module for each one, but I'm looking for another way, to add the sheets in the same codes, for example: (Jan_2), (Jan_3), (Jan_4)... etc.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it already looks like working code. I don't think it's necessary to preselect C4:J43 and scroll the window (the first two lines in the code). Now look - in your code, the name of the sheet "Jan_1" occurs three times. Replace this string with a variable, for example, sSheetName, and specify this variable as a parameter to your procedure, `Sub SortByTime(ByVal sSheetName As String)`. Now write another procedure that will sequentially call this one with different parameters: (just for example) `Call SortByTime("Jan_1") : Call SortByTime("Jan_2") : Call SortByTime("Jan_3")` etc

Comment: That's great idea, but what if we look at it in the opposite way?
In fact, I need this code to affect 365 pages
Can I make this code affect all pages except for some other pages (exactly 24 pages)
so instead of call the days names (Jan_1, Jan_2,.. etc), calling the other pages ("Total"), ("JAN_NOTES"), ... etc

Comment: That's right, I didn't describe it because I don't know exactly what sheets are in your workbook. In fact, the "main procedure" should go through each sheet in your workbook and check if the name of the next sheet is included in the "exclusion list". If not, then call the sorting procedure, if yes, then skip this sheet and move on. How the "list of exceptions" will be arranged, you must figure out yourself. For example, it could be a long string like "Total JAN_NOTES FEB_NOTES..." and you would use the InStr() function to check the next name.

Comment: How to enumerate through all the sheets of the book, see the article [**Macro to Loop Through All Worksheets in a Workbook**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/macro-to-loop-through-all-worksheets-in-a-workbook-feef14e3-97cf-00e2-538b-5da40186e2b0)

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the trick:

```
Sub SortByTime()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim RangeToSort As Range
    
    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wrkSht
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column G. The 7 in .Cells(..) is column G.
            Set RangeToSort = .Range(.Cells(3, 3), .Cells(LastRow, 10))
            
            Select Case .Name
                Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4" 'Add the sheets you want to sort here.
                    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
                    .Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Range(.Cells(4, 7), .Cells(LastRow, 7)), _
                                          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                          Order:=xlAscending, _
                                          DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    With .Sort
                        .SetRange RangeToSort
                        .Header = xlYes
                        .MatchCase = False
                        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                        '.SortMethod = xlPinYin  Not needed used for sorting Chinese characters.
                        .Apply
                    End With
                    
                'Case else isn't needed - just there to show nothing happens
                'with other sheets.  If you're sorting a lot of sheets then might be better
                'to put sorting code in here and list the sheets you don't want sorting above.
                Case Else
                    'Do nothing
            End Select
            
        End With
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```

Further reading:
[With...End With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement)
[ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook)
[Select Case Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement)